# Lego Star Wars the Complete Saga: Chapter 6 Episode 2

Tags: xbox-360, lego-star-wars

I'm stuck on Chapter 6 of Episode 2 in Lego Star Wars the Complete Saga. I have brought Count Dooku down to 4 hearts but cannot figure out how to harm him after that. I have tried many things, but none seem to work. It would be awesome if anyone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is, to wait until he zaps you with Force Lightning.  Then, switch to your other character and attack (the Jedi Slam works well here).

Here's a video demonstrating how this is done (fast-fowrard to the 04:30 mark).

And I apologize for how annoying the audio is.  I recommend muting.

Comment: I tried that but I dont think I did it correctly. Thanks!